# Uploading png images going black

Tags: php

I have searched the web and found many treads on this one,
but i can not find a solution for my issue.

I'm able to upload jpg and jpeg files, but when uploading png files, they turn out black.

This is my code for uploading the png files:

```
$dest_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height); 

if($image_extension == ".png"){
        $source_image = imagecreatefrompng($temp_png_file); 
        imagecopyresampled($dest_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height); 
        imagepng($dest_image, $folder.$new_name);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: did you try it with different png files?

Comment: hi, i tried transparent and non transparent ones... 24bit and 8bit... no succes...

Comment: hm, works for me - either your GD installation is corrupted or all your test images are... can you try it on a different server/virtual box...?

Comment: tested with allot of png images, even from the net, no succes...

Comment: i'll try the script on my online site...

Comment: crazy idea... imagecreatetruecolor creates a black image per default - can you make sure that the if-part is executed at all?

Comment: i have found something, but not yet the solution.
when i echo $source image when uploading a jpg file, i get somthing like Resource id #9.
When i upload a png file i get nothing...
This sounds not ok...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, 
It was because of a mysql_real_escape_string() function than created the wrong value for $temp_png_file.
Also, i had a problematic if() statement...

Twice my own mistake :-/